# How can I get some images with flow from directory?

Tags: tf.keras

In below example I want to take some images to train not all because my computer's efficiency is low.

How I can do that with flow_from_directory?

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      '/train/,
      target_size=(img_height, img_width),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      class_mode='categorical')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My batch size is 20 here. You can iterate over to get the images:

```
image_list = []

for images,labels in next(zip(train_generator)):
  for i in range(16): # can't be greater than 20
    image_list.append(images[i])

image_list = np.array(image_list)
image_list.shape # (16,150,150,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data generator will help us in pro-processing (rescaling) our images

```
data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, validation_split=0.2)
```

Use the `validation_split` to create for train and val datasets

```
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    target_size=(Img_size, Img_size),
    batch_size=Batch_size,
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True)
```

create val generator

```
val_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    target_size=(Img_size, Img_size),
    batch_size=Batch_size,
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=True)
```